# RESP format for HMSET in REDIS

Tags: serialization, redis, etl, bulkinsert

I am trying to mass insert a table data into redis hash using RESP protocol, using the traditional SQL at Oracle side.

I have constructed the RESP protocol format for the data:

table data:

```
col1-----col2

  v1-----v2
```

RESP format:

```
"*6\r\n$5\r\nHMSET\r\n$4\r\nkey1\r\n$4\r\ncol1\r\n$1\r\n1\r\n$4\r\ncol2\r\n$1\r\n2\r\n"
```

EDIT:

saving this output in a file, to feed it to the REDIS client through piping, for mass insertion."

What am I missing here? When I try to run it in the shell, I get this error:

> $ cat test_1.dat | redis-cli --pipe
>
> All data transferred. Waiting for the last reply...
>
> ERR unknown command '*6 $5 HMSET $4 key1 $4 col1 $1 1 $4 col2 $1 2 '
>
> Last reply received from server.
>
> errors: 1, replies: 1

Please help me! Wasted almost a day trying to find the issue in the RESP format but in vain. After reading many web pages, I found that mass insert is the best option (performance-wise) so I would like to stick to that as a solution, using RESP for HMSET.

Comment: How exactly are you planning to interact with redis from within oracle?

Comment: am trying to extract the RESP output format from the SQL query and store it in a file. feed the file to redis client piping for mass insert. i kind of missed that point in the above. will edit it. thanks.

Comment: Try `cat -e test_1.dat`. What's the output?

Comment: "*6\r\n$5\r\nHMSET\r\n$4\r\nkey3\r\n$4\r\ncol1\r\n$1\r\n1\r\n$4\r\ncol2\r\n$1\r\n2\r\n"$

Comment: yeah, so you have **literal string** "\r\n" (4 bytes) instead of CRLF (2 bytes)

Comment: am picking up on teh unix/redis resp... please help me correct it. Thanks!

Comment: And just one more thing for your note: i manually typed-in the data into the file before running it. does that have anything to do with 4 bytes issue?

Comment: Yes, it has everything to do with this. :) If you're on windows, then you can just type this command in the notepad (replacing each "\r\n" with pressing ENTER). Should look like this: http://monosnap.com/image/hGmxFOOMhTVwNLg5NCQMAeS1tq9mfJ.png

OSX and linux, however, don't have CRLF as default end-of-line character, so this will not work on these OSes.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline

Comment: :-| so dumb of me. Thanks for your patience and replies :). tested it using python and it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that line endings are broken in your `test1.dat` file (that is, they aren't ASCII `\r\n`). I was able to successfully do this.

Prepare the file (from ruby script)

```
s = "*6\r\n$5\r\nHMSET\r\n$4\r\nkey3\r\n$4\r\ncol1\r\n$1\r\n1\r\n$4\r\ncol2\r\n$1\r\n2\r\n"

file = File.new("/Users/sergio/redis_test.txt", 'w')
file.write s
file.close
```

Run it

```
% cat redis_test.txt | redis-cli --pipe
All data transferred. Waiting for the last reply...
Last reply received from server.
errors: 0, replies: 1
```

Result:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> hgetall key3
1) "col1"
2) "1"
3) "col2"
4) "2"
```

Comment: Thanks for quickly testing it on your side Sergio and confirming nothings is wrong with the data. One quick check on the error which i pasted in teh original message - all the \r\n is gone and blank spaces are shown. can this have anything to do or is it just a representation in the error message? I am using Ubuntu Trusty version and Redis 3 stable for testing. Thanks again and appreciate your responses.